# Create and delete files in one process

Tags: powershell

I was hoping someone could help me with a problem I am having with a PowerShell that I am running in ISE.

I need to read through a folder searching for pdf files that have a predefined prefix & email address eg. waynewayne.me@myemail.co.uk.pdf copy a pdf file and rename it before automatically emailing it to the email within the file name. eg. attach wayne.pdf and send it to wayne.me@myemail.co.uk.  I then need to move the original file to a complete folder (prefixed by date_time) and also remove/delete the newly created wayne.pdf.

I have got all of it perfectly except the remove/delete of the newly created file.  It errors saying:-

> Remove-item : cannot remove item
>   \ldmbc3048**\c$\Temp\Schools\emailfiles\wayne.pdf: The process cannot
>   access the file ‘\ldmbc3048**\c$\Temp\Schools\emailfiles\wayne.pdf’
>   because it is used by another process.

**Here is my code:**

```
$Attach = $SearchFolder + $Attachment
$copy-item $file.FullName $attach

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$msg.From = $smtpFrom
$msg.To.Add($smtpTo)
$msg.Subject = $MessageSubject
$msg.Body = $body
$msg.Attachments.Add($Attach)
$smtp.Send($msg)
remove-item $Attach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to *dispose* the `Net.Mail.MailMessage` object:

```
# ....
$msg.Dispose()
remove-item $Attach
```

Comment: You are an absolute star Martin.  Problem solved thank you.